# Kendo UI chart scatter chart get chart-circle value

Tags: charts, kendo-ui

I want to get the value of the y axis when I move mouse anywhere on the chart.
[image]

I refereed many links, but not found the way yet.

Can anyone please help??

Thank you

Comment: Anywhere? I would have thought that you only need the tooltip upon the dot like this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/index

Comment: I already have tool tip, just visibility is false right now. Real problem is, I do not get the value of the circle when I move mouse above parallel to the circle. As you can see in the screen shot, I will not get the circle value when I move mouse just above the circle.